# Do some pokemon players not see all pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

My son and I play Pokemon Go together. I use a google account and he has a PTC account, as he is under 13. We each have our own Android device.

On his game, he does not see the Starbucks stops. Is this expected? Have you encountered this with other sponsored stops (like Sprint stores?) Is there any way to allow him to see the sponsored stops, short of fibbing about his age or switching him to a google account?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Recently](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=pokestops&f=i-cannot-see-sponsored-pokestops-or-gyms&l=en), Niantic has provided the ability to enable sponsored Pokestops and Gyms for child accounts using [Niantic Kids](https://parents.nianticlabs.com)

> If your child logs into Pokémon GO using Niantic Kids, you can opt into enabling sponsored content for your child in the Niantic Kids Parent Portal, which will allow your child to be able to interact with sponsored locations.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> At this time, this functionality is only available for Niantic Kids accounts. We hope to make it available to Pokémon Trainer Club accounts in the future.

---

This is intended. PokéStops and Gyms at sponsored locations are hidden from those who are under the age of 13

[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/236150508-I-cannot-see-sponsored-Pok%C3%A9Stops-or-Gyms)

> Sponsored locations (branded PokéStops and Gyms created through partnership agreements with Niantic) are only available to Trainers ages 13 or over. Trainers under the age of 13 are not able to see or interact with sponsored locations.

Niantic wrote a [blog](https://nianticlabs.com/blog/sponsored_loc/) clarifying this on 12/14/2016, which I found was in response to a [letter](http://www.commercialfreechildhood.org/sites/default/files/LetterToNiantic.pdf) from [Campaign for a Commercial Free Childhood](http://commercialfreechildhood.org/) on 12/13/2016